# Artdarek's Twitter client from the command line

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm using Laravel with artdarek oauth authentication library. It's all working fine for the web application. However, I have a running cron job that requires Twitter authentication in order to use Twitter's API. I wasn't able to find a solution as all examples requires a redirect Twitter's page in order to authenticate.

Is there any way to authenticate to Twitter from the command line using artdarek library? I don't want to authenticate on behalf of a user, I just want to be authenticated using my key/secret in order for me to use some of their apis.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this?

Comment: unfortunately not @uɐɥʇɐᴎ, I used this library: https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tw = SocialToken::where('provider', 'twitter')->first();
$c = new tmhOAuth([
    'consumer_key'    => $tw->consumer_key,
    'consumer_secret' => $tw->consumer_secret,
    'user_token'      => $tw->user_key,
    'user_secret'     => $tw->user_secret,
]);

$c->request('GET', $c->url('1.1/search/tweets'), ['q' => $query, 'lang' => 'en', 'count' => '100']);

$tweets = json_decode($c->response['response'], true);
```

This is my solution. I just cut out the libraries as they aren't needed for this.

Only had to add the dependency `"themattharris/tmhoauth": "*"`, which is used for most of these libraries as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I ended up using https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php :).